# How to uninstall SBT in Ubuntu?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sbt

My current installed SBT is corrupted and I want to reinstall it. The problem is I didn't install SBT through `sudo apt-get` command. I followed the tutorial here: [Functional Programming Principles in Scala | Coursera](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/wiki/ToolsSetup).

Instructions that I followed from the webpage:

- Download sbt from here: http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/sbt.tgz
- Unpack the archive to a directory of your choice
- Add the bin/ directory to the PATH environment variable. Open the file `~/.bashrc` in a text editor (create it if it doesn’t exist), and add the following line `export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH`

So how do I uninstall SBT on Ubuntu in the first place?

I tried running `sudo apt-get remove sbt` but it didn't work. These are the results of `sudo apt-get remove sbt` :

```
$ sudo apt-get remove sbt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'sbt' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ax25-node libax25 libossp-uuid16 openbsd-inetd
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 324 not upgraded.
```

Comment: First, the question probably belongs on [ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). But even then, without defining "doesn't work", you are unlikely to get an constructive help.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback. I'll post another one on Ubuntu then.

Comment: You haven't _installed_ SBT so you cannot uninstall it. Simply reverse the steps you listed above; delete it from your `PATH` and delete the directory. Where are you having issues?

Answer (score 3):

> Open the file ~/.bashrc in an editor (create it if it doesn’t exist) and add the following line export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH

The path to your sbt/bin is already stored in your ~/.bashrc file. If you know the path to sbt/bin, you can delete the sbt directory and its contents manually from the terminal using `sudo rm -r ./sbt/` from where you unpacked it.

Afterwards delete the obsolete `export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH` line from your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Hey karel, I have updated my question. I didn't install sbt using dpkg in the first place. That's why sudo apt-get remove doesn't work.

Comment: I know you prtobably installed it from the .deb package, called something like sbt-0.13.5.deb. The dpkg command is being used only to search for the package name of sbt by grepping the list of installed packages which s explained more fully in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448844/finding-installed-software/448848#448848)

Comment: dpkg -l | grep sbt doesn't return any results. Any ideas?

Comment: Open the Ubuntu Software Center. Click on the **Installed** icon in the top menu bar. Click on the black arrow to the left of the **Developer Tools** heading to unfold the list of installed Developer Tools. Look for all packages in the list of installed Developer Tools that have sbt or scala in their names. If that doesn't work then click on the **History** icon and search backwards through the history of installed packages for that sbt package you installed.

Comment: Nah neither SBT/Scala is not there. Can you please check my question? I have updated it with the instructions i followed.

Comment: Regarding enzyme's comment that SBT is uninstalled, I want to highlight that I am still able to run 'sbt -h' from CLI